# empty variables in php email form

Tags: php, html

I have a simple email form in a php file and i try to send emails but it seems that my variables come null. I have an echo after my code just to test if my variables have any values inside and they are not printed. The only thing that is printed is the 'done' and the 'email $to'. Do i do anything wrong? I followed this method from a post in youtube and he did the exact same thing and it worked for him. I also tried more email php files but still nothing. 
Here is my html and php code.

php code:

```
 <?php 

$name = $_REQUEST['author'];
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$subj = $_REQUEST['sub'];
$message = $_REQUEST['msg'];

$headers .= "From: ".$from;

$to = "mygmail@gmail.com";

$subject = $subj;
$body = $message;

if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) {
echo "An e-mail was sent to ".$to." with the subject: ".$subject;
} else {
echo "There was a problem sending the mail. Check your code and make sure that the e-mail address ".$to." is valid";
}

?>
```

html code:

```
<form action="formtoemail.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                            <p>
                                <label for="author">Name:</label> 
                                <input type="text" id="author" name="author" class="required input_field" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="email">Email:</label> 
                                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate-email required input_field" />
                            </p>
                            <p class="no_margin_right">
                                <label for="subject">Subject:</label> 
                                <input type="text" name="sub" id="sub" class="input_field" />
                            </p>
                            <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

                            <label for="text">Message:</label> 
                            <textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
                            <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

                            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" />
                            <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" name="reset" class="submit_btn float_r" />
                      </form>
```

Comment: now i get the values. but i get error in the if statement. it progs the else of my if statement: /

Comment: Try PEAR Mail Package to sendmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending via `POST` and retriving  via `GET` try `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` in PHP

OR in HTML -

Chenge from action to `GET` instead of `POST`

Comment: Oh damn i posted the code with get. i didnt notice. I had initialy my code with post. Still didnt work.

Comment: @lantonis update with the latest code then.

Comment: just did. Now i get values from variables. but i get error in my if statement. i get the else from my if statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code change "POST" method to "GET"

```
<form action="formtoemail.php" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
                        <p>
                            <label for="author">Name:</label> 
                            <input type="text" id="author" name="author" class="required input_field" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="email">Email:</label> 
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate-email required input_field" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="no_margin_right">
                            <label for="subject">Subject:</label> 
                            <input type="text" name="sub" id="sub" class="input_field" />
                        </p>
                        <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

                        <label for="text">Message:</label> 
                        <textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
                        <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

                        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" name="reset" class="submit_btn float_r" />
                  </form>
```

Comment: I changed the post in my html form and now the variables are ok. But i get the else statement in my if statement. Why doesnt it validate ?

Answer (score 0):

Use "get" method:

```
<form action="formtoemail.php" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
$headers .= "From: $email";
```

To this:

```
$headers = "From: ".$from;
```

And also change this:

```
$subject = "$subj";
$body = "$message";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "An e-mail was sent to $to with the subject: $subject";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem sending the mail. Check your code and make sure that the e-mail address $to is valid";
}
```

To this:

```
$subject = $subj;
$body = $message;

if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "An e-mail was sent to ".$to." with the subject: ".$subject;
} else {
    echo "There was a problem sending the mail. Check your code and make sure that the e-mail address ".$to." is valid";
}
```

Comment: that helped out m8 thanks. But now i get error on my if statement. It procs the else statement in my if. Any idea why?

Comment: @lantonis i haven't tested above code if errors do tell me :)

Comment: well i do get the error in my if statement. I get the  "There was a problem sending the mail. Check your code and make sure that the e-mail address ".$to." is valid"; message. And obviously i dont have any new emails in my inbox. its really driving my crazy the last days:P it must be something really simple yet its still uncompleted.

Comment: i changed it as you did here and still i get the error message :(

Comment: ok buddy i will talk to you tommorow about your matter

Comment: @AspiringAqib You forgot him?